# SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I have some Stored procedure like this, i want to insert Header and Detail in one StoredProcedure and i make this Sp. To insert Detail data i am used WHILE for loop.

I have tried to insert data but error Exception like this:

> "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Maybe someone can help me

```
CREATE DEFINER=`core_php`@`%` PROCEDURE `bankTransaction_insert_v1802`(
    IN $IndexBankAccount varchar(50), 
    IN $BankName varchar(50), 
    IN $BankAccount varchar(50), 
    IN $Divisi varchar(100),
    IN $Category varchar(100), 
    IN $ReferenceManual varchar(100), 
    IN $Attention varchar(50), 
    IN $Description varchar(1000), 
    IN $ChequeNo varchar(50), 
    IN $Currency varchar(50), 
    IN $Amount decimal(20,2), 
    IN $Status varchar(100), 
    IN $PostingDate varchar(20), 
    #IN $IDReport varchar(100), 
    #IN $Source varchar(100),
    IN $PrintStatus tinyint(1),
    #IN $ReferenceID varchar(100),
    #IN $SettlementSource varchar(50),
    IN $CompanyID int(11),
    #IN $RemarksDeveloper text,
    #IN $VirtualAccountNo varchar(100),
    #IN $PTCID varchar(100),
    IN $CreatedDate datetime ,
    IN $CreatedByID varchar(50) ,
    IN $CreatedByName varchar(200),

    ##
    IN $TransactionType varchar(100),
    IN $CL_ReferenceID LONGTEXT ,
    IN $CL_Currency LONGTEXT ,
    IN $CL_PaymentRate LONGTEXT ,
    IN $CL_PaymentAmount LONGTEXT
)
BEGIN
    ##BankTransaction Declaration
    DECLARE $temp int;
    DECLARE $temp2 int;
    DECLARE $DivisiNo varchar(50);
    DECLARE $BankTransactionID varchar(50);

    ##BankTransactionDetail Declaration
    DECLARE $ReferenceID  varchar(100);
    #DECLARE $Currency  varchar(100);
    DECLARE $PaymentRate decimal(20,2) ;
    DECLARE $PaymentAmount decimal(20,2);
    DECLARE $USER_ID varchar(100);

    DECLARE $OriginalCurrency  VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE $OriginalAmount  decimal(20,2);
    DECLARE $OriginalOutstanding  decimal(20,2);
    DECLARE $OriginalPaid  decimal(20,2);
    DECLARE $Outstanding  decimal(20,2);

    DECLARE $IndexBankTransaction int;

    SET $DivisiNo = (SELECT DivisiNo from Divisi where DivisiID = $Divisi);     
    SET $BankTransactionID = (select BankTransactionID from `BankTransaction` where Category = $Category and SUBSTRING(BankTransactionID, 3,2) = $DivisiNo order by BankTransactionID desc LIMIT 1);                                    


    IF ($BankTransactionID is null and $Category = 'DEBET') THEN
        SET $BankTransactionID = 'BM' + $DivisiNo + '-' + '0000001';
    ELSEIF ($BankTransactionID is not null and $Category = 'DEBET') THEN
        SELECT $temp = cast(SUBSTRING($BankTransactionID,7,7) as UNSIGNED) + 1 ;
        SET $BankTransactionID = 'BM' + $DivisiNo + '-' + right('0000000' + cast($temp as CHAR ), 7);
    ELSEIF ($BankTransactionID is null and $Category = 'CREDIT') THEN 
        SET $BankTransactionID = 'BK' + $DivisiNo + '-' + '0000001';
    ELSEIF ($BankTransactionID is not null and $Category = 'CREDIT') THEN
        SELECT $temp = cast(SUBSTRING($BankTransactionID,7,7) as UNSIGNED) + 1 ;
        set $BankTransactionID = 'BK' + $DivisiNo + '-' + right('0000000' + cast($temp as CHAR), 7);    
    else
        set $BankTransactionID = $BankTransactionID;    
    END IF ;

    #Insert BankTransaction
    INSERT INTO `core_kenji`.`BankTransaction`
        (`BankTransactionID`,
        `IndexBankAccount`,
        `BankName`,
        `BankAccount`,
        `Divisi`,
        `Category`,
        `ReferenceManual`,
        `Attention`,
        `Description`,
        `ChequeNo`,
        `Currency`,
        `Amount`,
        `Status`,
        `PostingDate`,
        #`IDReport`,
        #`Source`,
        `PrintStatus`,
        #`ReferenceID`,
        #`SettlementSource`,
        `CompanyID`,
        #`RemarksDeveloper`,
        #`VirtualAccountNo`,
        #`PTCID`,
        `CreatedDate`,
        `CreatedByID`,
        `CreatedByName`)
    VALUES
        ($BankTransactionID,
            $IndexBankAccount,
            $BankName,
            $BankAccount,
            $Divisi,
            UPPER($Category),
            UPPER($ReferenceManual),
            UPPER($Attention),
            UPPER(REPLACE($Description, char(13), '<br />')),
            UPPER($ChequeNo),
            UPPER($Currency),
            $Amount,
            'OPEN',
            CASE WHEN ($PostingDate is not NULL) then CONVERT($PostingDate, datetime) ELSE NULL END,
            #$IDReport,
            #$Source,
            $PrintStatus,
            #$ReferenceID,
            #$SettlementSource,
            $CompanyID,
            #$RemarksDeveloper,
            #$VirtualAccountNo,
            #$PTCID,
            NOW(),
            $CreatedByID,
            $CreatedByName
        );


    set $IndexBankTransaction = (
        SELECT IndexBankTransaction FROM BankTransaction WHERE BankTransactionID = $BankTransactionID
    );

    ##lOOPING
    #IF(CHARINDEX('|', $CL_ReferenceID) > 0) THEN
        SET $temp = 1;
        SET $temp2 = CHARINDEX('|', $CL_ReferenceID);
        WHILE ((CHARINDEX('|', $CL_ReferenceID) + 1 ) > 0) DO
            ##SET DECLARATION
            SET $ReferenceID = CASE WHEN $temp2 > 0 THEN (SPLIT_STRING($CL_ReferenceID, '|', $temp)) ELSE $CL_ReferenceID END; 
            SET $Currency = CASE WHEN $temp2 > 0 THEN (SPLIT_STRING($CL_Currency, '|', $temp)) ELSE $CL_Currency END;   
            SET $PaymentRate =  CASE WHEN $temp2 > 0 THEN (CAST((SPLIT_STRING($CL_PaymentRate, '|', $temp)) AS DECIMAL(20,2))) ELSE CAST($CL_PaymentRate AS DECIMAL(20,2)) END; ##CONVERT
            SET $PaymentAmount = CASE WHEN $temp2 > 0 THEN (CAST((SPLIT_STRING($CL_PaymentAmount, '|', $temp)) AS DECIMAL(20,2))) ELSE CAST($CL_PaymentAmount AS DECIMAL(20,2)) END;    ##CONVERT

            IF( $TransactionType = 'PRV') THEN
                SET $OriginalCurrency = (SELECT Currency FROM PrvHeader WHERE PRVID = $ReferenceID);
                SET $OriginalAmount = (SELECT TotalAmount FROM PrvHeader WHERE PRVID = $ReferenceID);
                SET $OriginalOutstanding = (SELECT FinalOutstanding FROM PrvHeader WHERE PRVID = $ReferenceID);
            ELSEIF($TransactionType = 'CASH ADVANCE') THEN
                SET $OriginalCurrency = (SELECT Currency FROM CashAdvance WHERE CashAdvanceID = $ReferenceID);
                SET $OriginalAmount = (SELECT Amount FROM CashAdvance WHERE CashAdvanceID = $ReferenceID);
                SET $OriginalOutstanding = (SELECT OutstandingAmount FROM CashAdvance WHERE CashAdvanceID = $ReferenceID);
            ELSEIF($TransactionType = 'REFUND DEPOSIT') THEN
                SET $OriginalCurrency = (SELECT Currency FROM Deposit WHERE PRVID = $ReferenceID);
                SET $OriginalAmount = (SELECT DepositAmount FROM Deposit WHERE PRVID = $ReferenceID);
                SET $OriginalOutstanding = (SELECT OutstandingDeposit FROM Deposit WHERE PRVID = $ReferenceID);
            ELSEIF($TransactionType = 'NO DOCUMENT') THEN
                SET $OriginalCurrency = $Currency;
                SET $OriginalAmount = ($PaymentRate * $PaymentAmount);
                SET $OriginalOutstanding = ($PaymentRate * $PaymentAmount);
            END IF;

            SET $Outstanding = $OriginalOutstanding - ($PaymentRate * $PaymentAmount);
            SET $OriginalPaid = ($PaymentRate * $PaymentAmount);

            ##INSERT BankTransactionDetail
            INSERT INTO `core_kenji`.`BankTransactionDetail`
            (
                `IndexBankTransaction`,
                `BankTransactionID`,
                `ReferenceID`,
                `OriginalCurrency`,
                `OriginalAmount`,
                `OriginalPaid`,
                `Outstanding`,
                `PaymentCurrency`,
                `PaymentRate`,
                `PaymentAmount`#,
            )
            VALUES
            (
                $IndexBankTransaction,
                $BankTransactionID,
                $ReferenceID,
                $OriginalCurrency,
                $OriginalAmount,
                $OriginalPaid,
                $Outstanding,
                $Currency,
                $PaymentRate,
                $PaymentAmount#,
            );
            SET $temp = $temp + 1;
        END WHILE; 
    #END IF;
END
```

Comment: The error is clear, one of your `SELECT` statement is returning more than one row and you cant assign to a variable. Create debug point to found out which `SELECT` is the culprit

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Oh thanks, something wrong with my data.